# How to make CORBA between Java server and C++ client?

Tags: java, c++, rmi, corba, idl

I came to know that IDL is used for communication between server and client in CORBA, which is independent of languages.

As far as I know there is a plugin available for Eclipse (for creating the server of CORBA). For C++, OmniORB, Taox and etc.,

Suggest me the best tool and best practice for creating client in C++, which is having less dependencies and very good support for Java Server.

Comment: For implementing the C++ part you have several CORBA implementations to choose from, TAO (http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu), OmniORB (http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/), TAOX11 (http://swsupport.remedy.nl). TAOX11 is a new implementation supporting the IDL to C++11 Language Mapping.

Comment: Examples of the IDL to C++11 way of implementing a CORBA client is online at https://osportal.remedy.nl/projects/idl2cppx0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a remote interface in Java.
2. Generate a server POA, with `rmic -iiop`.
3. Define a server implementation that extends the POA.
4. Generate the IDL, with `rmic -idl.`
5. Follow the normal steps for your ORB to write your client given the IDL.